# Planar Homographies in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have taken an image in height 2 meters of the ground as the original image and I want to simulate another image in 50 cm's of the ground, such as the simulated image.

The focal length of my camera is 3.7 mm (`f = 3.7`).

I have used from planar homography: `H = k'*(eye(3) - ((t*n')/d))*inv(k)` for each plane in original image in MATLAB where in the camera coordinate system:

- x axis is perpendicular to buildings in the right side of the ground,
- y axis is parallel to the ground,
- and hence z axis is upward perpendicular to the ground.

The origin is camera location in original image and `k` is 3x3 camera calibration matrix:

`[f 0 0;
  0 f 0;
  0 0 1]`

`t` is the transfer matrix `[0 0 -1.5]`, `n` is the normal vector of a plane, `d` is the plane distance to the origin, and `eye(3)` is camera rotation.

For example, the plane of the ground has `n=[0 0 1]` and `d = 2`, is it true?

Please help me with implementation of other planes (sky, buildings) in MATLAB.

Original image:
[image: original image]

Simulated image:
[image: simulated image]

Answer (score 2):

No can do. Your scene is not not planar, nor the camera motion you want to simulate is a pure rotation about the camera's center (a "pan-tilt"). These are the only cases where an image transformation with a pure homography will yield a realistic result.

One thing you can do is select one of the planes apparent in the image, and then
warp the whole image applying a homography to it - for example, you could make the left-side wall appear frontal. But your example has real parallax between the views, so it cannot be achieved with a homography.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me a useful link for the samples of this work?

Comment: Here's the whole mother lode: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/
(upvoting and/or accepting the answer if you find it useful would be nice too ;-)